# How to Solve Pages with Duplicate Meta Duplicate Tags & Content Error due to multilingual pages?

Tags: seo, canonical-url, rel-canonical, hreflang, technical-seo

I am using one of popular SEO tool and it showing me error of duplicate meta tags and content for below type of URL structures (I am taking as example) and I am working for agency.

`www.example.com/abc/`

`www.example.com/en_US/abc/`

Current there are no any canonical URLs

What's the best solution to avoid duplicate meta tags issues for this?

I was thinking to add below attributes, let me know if this is correct This is what I am thinking I am going to add below meta attributes for both pages `example.com/abc`

```
<link rel=“canonical” href=“example.com/abc” /> 
<link rel="alternate" href="example.com/abc" hreflang="en"> 
<link rel="alternate" href="example.com/en_us/abc" hreflang="en-US">  
<link rel="alternate" href="example.com/abc" hreflang="x-default">
```

and same attributes for this page

`example.com/en_US/abc`

Answer (score 0):

`www.example.com/abc`

will have these attributes:

```
<link rel=“canonical” href=“example.com/abc” /> 
<link rel="alternate" href="example.com/abc" hreflang="en"> 
<link rel="alternate" href="example.com/en_us/abc" hreflang="en-US">  
<link rel="alternate" href="example.com/abc" hreflang="x-default">
```

`www.example.com/en_US/abc` will have :

```
<link rel=“canonical” href=“www.example.com/en_US/abc” /> 
<link rel="alternate" href="example.com/abc" hreflang="en"> 
<link rel="alternate" href="example.com/en_us/abc" hreflang="en-US">  
<link rel="alternate" href="example.com/abc" hreflang="x-default">
```

note that the slashes at the end need to be added to all if your site using them else dont add the slashes at then of urls

Comment: Thanks Yahia, but keeping URLs canonical tags separate will solve the duplicate titles & content issue?